# rosserial_python arduino node queue_size problem

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When launching rosserial_python I receive the following warning:

- /rosdistro: indigo
- /rosversion: 1.11.10
- /serial_node/baud: 57600
- /serial_node/port: /dev/ttyACM0

NODES
/
serial_node (rosserial_python/serial_node.py)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [6087]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to f6d85ce2-9af7-11e4-b2dc-eca86bf8a38d
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [6100]
started core service [/rosout]
process[serial_node-2]: started with pid [6117]
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosserial_python/SerialClient.py:336: SyntaxWarning: The publisher should be created with an explicit keyword argument 'queue_size'. Please see http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers for more information.
self.pub_diagnostics = rospy.Publisher('/diagnostics', diagnostic_msgs.msg.DiagnosticArray)
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosserial_python/SerialClient.py:101: SyntaxWarning: The publisher should be created with an explicit keyword argument 'queue_size'. Please see http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers for more information.
self.publisher = rospy.Publisher(self.topic, self.message)

How can I fix it ?

I've tried to change my arduino code:

ros::Publisher pub("/MockBot/adc", &adc_msg, queue_size=1);

But I now the compiler throw me errors...

Where is the trick to make it work ?

Thanks in advance
Christian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200869/rosserial_python-arduino-node-queue_size-problem/) by [Chrimo](https://answers.ros.org/users/361/chrimo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 390 on 2015-01-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a warning in the rosserial_python node; not in your arduino program.

This particular warning is just a warning; you can ignore it and your code will continue to work reasonably well. You can learn more about the details by reading the link mentioned in the warning.

You should check the rosserial_python bug tracker to see if this has been reported or fixed, and if it hasn't you should report it as a bug.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2015-02-27**:
I just observed this warning, too! Opened issue oh github:
https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/issues/167